# How to solve "ImportError: No module named dis3" when making stand-alone executable file from python script

Tags: python, pyinstaller

On a windows 7 (64-bits) machine I installed python 2.7. 
Then installed pyinstaller, pypiwin32, pywin32-ctypes in this order, by running "pip install pyinstaller" etc in command prompt. Each time some files were downloaded and a success message was shown.
Then I restarted my computer.

After doing above, I ran "pyinstaller" in command prompt (just this, didnt  mention the python code file I wrote) to test the installions. 
I get a detailed error message, whose last line is shown below (the whole error message is I think too cumbersome and unnecessary to be shown here):

```
C:\Python27>pyinstaller 
ImportError: No module named dis3
```

Same error came when I ran the command from c:\python27, c:\python27\scripts.

Same error also came when I ran the command mentioning my python code file from above directories and also from the directory where my python code file is.

The other questions here related to import errors mentioning some modules when running pyinstaller command are about programming errors inside users' codes such as not mentioning a module in import statement because of hidden dependency etc. I think my error is related to installation (because as stated above, even when I dont pass my code file to the command same error comes).

Is the problem with installion or with my code? 
If the problem is with installion, what do I need to install or uninstall, and in which order?

If the problem is in my code then what do I have to import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dis3 is not a dependency of pyinstaller. You must install it via `pip install dis3`.
This is needed only if you're trying to "pyinstall" a bunch of code written in python 2.7

Comment: Why do the error come even when I didnt mention my source code file name to pyinstaller? It cannot tell that my code is in python 2.7 or some other version.

Comment: pyinstaller requires dis3 when run under python2.7. In your case, if you type "python", the interpreter must be a 2.x version. pyinstaller is a python script and it uses your python default python interpreter.

Comment: I followed your advice as soon as I got access to the computer I was practising python 2.7 on. It worked! Thanks a lot. Already upvoted both your comment and your answer.